# Creating graph in QGIS

Tags: qgis, graph

[image]I have created the snow cover map using the NDSI technique. I want to create a graph showing the snow's areal extent with progressing time. How can I create it?

Comment: Please could you include which version of QGIS you are using? Also have you tried anything so far/looked at any techniques?

Comment: Hello sorry for late reply. I am using QGIS 3.16.1 and i have already prepared the snow cover map of a part in himalaya. Pls see the edited post. I want to create that type of graph showing the areal extent of snow w.r.t time

Comment: No i dont want to create the animation just a 2d graph